# PHAsset CLLocation is not giving location same as photos app

Tags: ios, cllocation, phasset, phassetslibrary

We are fetching the latitude and longitude from PHAsset properties we are using `CLGeocoder` to `reverseGeocodeLocation` using following method.

```
CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [CLGeocoder new];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    CLPlacemark *placeInfo = placemarks[0];

}
```

we are getting placeInfo object but thoroughfare and subThoroughfare are always coming nil.

For the same photo photosapp is able to fetch thoroughfare and subThoroughfare.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

thoroughfare and subThoroughfare property that might not contain data for some places. So instead of creatying address string using thoroghfare and subThoroghfare, use addressdictionary as follow:

```
 NSString *address = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placeInfo .addressDictionary, NO);
```

Comment: I have tried using placeInfo .addressDictionary but it is also returning the same where i am not able to get thoroughfare and subThoroughfare values in it but iOS photos app some how managed to get it.